# Flutter, API sometimes stop working on application

Tags: flutter, api, dart, flutter-test

sometimes api at my application stop working but when I test it at postman I see no problem, I fetch it with http domain, so what could be the reason

Comment: This is *way* to vague. First, what does "stop working" mean? Do you get any errors?

Comment: no I didn't get any problems

Comment: uh... but you must have *some* problem, or you would not be posting here... again: what does "stopped working" mean? If you don't get errors, then maybe you get unexpected results?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.